# Where is this beach on Maui's north shore, in front of West Maui Mountains?

Tags: identify-this, maui

*DK Eyewitness Travel Guide Hawaii* (2017 edn). [p. 19](https://books.google.com/books?id=X-jtBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=%22the+most+isolated+land+masses+and+the+longest%22&source=bl&ots=alyEJWdJOR&sig=f0r54vDa6lPH3moO0dcUiCucABE&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> [image]

Comment: @Willeke I reverse-image-searched on Google, but no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be taken from [Baldwin Beach Park](https://www.google.com/maps/@20.913921,-156.3934977,3a,60y,255.48h,87.75t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1swPdbEhtmus7lMoLmRrBTWg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656). Unfortunately the Google Street View image appears to have been taken on a day with some clouds obscuring the mountains, but you can at least see the same pattern of trees as in your original image (indicated below).

[image]